# How to write to a specific range of a sheet in google sheets API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

This is my first time using the google sheets API, and I'm trying to write a script that takes in some data and processes it, which works, and then I want to write the processed data to a column in an already existing sheet, which it what I need help with.

Is there some better way to put an array in a specific range?

The error message says cannot get range of null, this is my code so far, the line that isn't part of the block is the issue:

```
function getList() {
    var spreadsheetId = '1BjnZ-SPBVcCdITxcvEX1nCPecvGdYSKQ0m_GiaKduZQ';
    var rangeName = 'Paste Here!I1:GZ6';
    var pasteRange = 'The Goods!B3:B1000';
    var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, rangeName).values;
    var width = values[0].length;
    var teamNumbers = [];
    if (!values) {
      Logger.log('No data found.');
    } else {
      for(var col = 1; col < width; col+=2) {
        for(var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {
          teamNumbers += values[row][col].toString();
          teamNumbers += '\n'
        }
      }
  
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(pasteRange).setValues(teamNumbers);
   
    }
}
```

Also, secondary question, how can you make the range for something a variable, as in in order to get I1:GZ6 from a parameter?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: add the language of the script too as a tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason you would get the error

> Cannot call method `getRange` of `null`

from the line `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` is if you are using a standalone script instead of a bound script. Standalone scripts must use `SpreadsheetApp.openById("some id")` in order to access a spreadsheet.

For more information on the differences, consult the Apps Script documentation

[Standalone scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)
[SpreadsheetApp#getActiveSpreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveSpreadsheet())

Answer (score 3):

### For your 1st question

How about this modification?

#### Modification points :

- `teamNumbers` is declared as an array. But it is used as string.

  - In order to import values to spreadsheet using Sheets API, `teamNumbers` has to be used as the 2 dimensional array.
  - If you want to import the string value in one cell,

    - In the case of use of Sheets API, please use `teamNumbers = [[value]]`.
    - In the case of use of `setValue(teamNumbers)` of `SpreadsheetApp`, please use `teamNumbers = value`.
- If you want to use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(pasteRange).setValues(teamNumbers)`, `pasteRange` is required to be matched to the size of rows and columns of `teamNumbers`.
- If you want to use `var rangeName = 'Paste Here!I1:GZ6'`, you can use `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update()` of Sheets API.

  - In this modification, this was used.

#### Modified script :

```
function getList() {
  var spreadsheetId = '1BjnZ-SPBVcCdITxcvEX1nCPecvGdYSKQ0m_GiaKduZQ';
  var rangeName = 'Paste Here!I1:GZ6';
  var pasteRange = 'The Goods!B3:B1000';
  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, rangeName).values;
  var width = values[0].length;
  var teamNumbers = [];
  if (!values) {
    Logger.log('No data found.');
  } else {
    for(var col = 1; col < width; col+=2) {
      for(var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {
        teamNumbers.push([values[row][col].toString()]); // Modified
      }
    }
    var spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(); // Modified
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({values: teamNumbers}, spreadsheetId, pasteRange, {valueInputOption: "RAW"}); // Modified
  }
}
```

#### Note :

- If the error related to API occurs, please confirm whether Sheets API is enabled at Advanced Google Services and API console, again.

#### Reference :

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

### For your 2nd question

If you want to convert the gridrange to a1notation, you can see a sample at [the document](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#gridrange) and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/95c7cd650837f33a564babcaf013cae0).

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much! What I meant for the second question was how do I pass a variable into the range, for example as the A1:I5 'sheet!A1:I5'

Comment: @NightOwl4321 use a different `getRange` signature: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer) If you already have the A1Notation string in a variable `theRangeStringVariable` then, calling `getRange(theRangeStringVariable)` will work.