# Start calculations only after CSV is fully imported

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm generating a CSV file every night as a download from a different system. I need this CSV imported into Google Sheets every day. My Google Sheets takes the CSV data and runs many different calculations on the data to produce my final data set.

I was able to make all this work by using a function to upload the CSV data into Google Sheets as shown below:

```
 function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

 var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("DualCreditExport.csv").next();
 var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('CURRENT');
 sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

This was working fine until my CSV file was over about 3500 rows. The reason being that as soon as a few rows are uploaded my google sheet's calculations begin to occur. They take a few minutes to run through then the upload continues and the calcs restart.

So basically, the import is constantly interrupted by the calculations which makes the import script exceed the maximum execution time.

However, the import script only takes 15 seconds to run. The calculations take about 5 minutes to run. So if I was able to complete the import then run the calculations I would be fine.

Any ideas on how to get the csv fully uploaded would be appreciated.

Comment: Use a separate script to do all of the calculations after the upload.

Comment: Thank you for the response Cooper. Someone else did all the calculations so I'm not sure how exactly to turn them into a script. Is there any other way?

Comment: Use the sheets api instead of setValues

Comment: @TheMaster please expand a little bit on this. I don't understand.

Comment: Use advanced services. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49870511 for a related sample

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid immediate recalculation is to use an stand-alone script project or a project bounded to a different spreadsheet and `SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)` or `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)` instead of `Spreadsheet.getActive();` in such way that the target spreadsheet isn't opened by a user during the import script execution. This because besides de computation required for the recalculation task there there is the sync task between the client that opened spreadsheet an the serve and there is no other way to pause/stop the recalculation.